# How to stop ffmpeg after it has finished python

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, python-3.6

I have a function that finds an mp4 video in a temp folder, converts it to an mp3 in a seperate folder, called music, and then deletes the mp4 from the temp folder. It looks like such:

```
import imageio
imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
import moviepy.editor as mp

def convert_mp4_to_mp3():
    video_file = os.listdir(os.getcwd() + '//temp')[0]
    audio_file = video_file.replace('mp4','mp3')
    clip = mp.VideoFileClip(os.getcwd() + '//temp//' + video_file)
    clip.audio.write_audiofile(os.getcwd() + '//music//' + audio_file)
    os.system("taskkill /f /im ffmpeg.win32.exe*32")
    os.remove(os.getcwd() + '//temp//' + video_file)
```

The function successfully completes the conversion of mp4 to mp3 but when I try and delete the file, I get the following error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it 
is being used by another process
```

Upon trying to manually delete the file, I discovered it was because "ffmpeg.win32.exe" is still running with the file open. I could not manually delete it until I killed that process.

I tried implementing the second to last line (os.system("taskkill /f /im ffmpeg.win32.exe*32") to kill the process but I still come up with the same error.

So my question is, is there a simple way to kill ffmpeg once I know I am done with it or is there a workaround to somehow kill it via another process? I am working in python3.6 on a windows 7 pc. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Try calling `clip.close()` instead of killing ffmpeg.

Comment: I get an error " 'VideoFileClip' object has no attribute 'close' "

Comment: Can this be a true copy of your code, with the double slashes ('//') in it?

Comment: Yes, the above is the exact code I have written. I need to use double slashes otherwise python gets confused for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want. In this code `clip` is an object instance that 'hangs on' to the video file until the instance itself is released. As with any other object whatever is assigned to `clip` can be released by assigning something else to `clip`, in this code the value `None`.

When I first attempt to remove the file, the attempt fails. After `clip = None` the removal request succeeds.

```
>>> import moviepy.editor as mp
>>> clip = mp.VideoFileClip('Tokens - The Lion Sleeps Tonight.mp4')
>>> clip.audio.write_audiofile('Tokens - The Lion Sleeps Tonight.mp3')
[MoviePy] Writing audio in Tokens - The Lion Sleeps Tonight.mp3

  0%|          | 0/4081 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
  0%|          | 2/4081 [00:00<03:38, 18.69it/s]
  1%|          | 28/4081 [00:00<02:39, 25.44it/s]
  3%|▎         | 121/4081 [00:00<01:50, 35.92it/s]
....
 99%|█████████▉| 4034/4081 [00:04<00:00, 993.74it/s]
100%|██████████| 4081/4081 [00:04<00:00, 833.74it/s]
[MoviePy] Done.
>>> os.remove('Tokens - The Lion Sleeps Tonight.mp4')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'Tokens - The Lion Sleeps Tonight.mp4'
>>> clip = None
>>> os.remove('Tokens - The Lion Sleeps Tonight.mp4')
```

**EDIT: And this is what I should have suggested!**

Yes, you need to discard `clip` but because `moviepy` uses ffmpeg to do most of its work you need to allow time for ffmpeg to release *its* resources. Hence, the need for `time.sleep(2)` or some more sophisticated way of suspending the function until ffmpeg disappears from execution.

```
import imageio
imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
import moviepy.editor as mp
import os
import time

def convert_mp4_to_mp3():
    video_file = os.listdir(os.getcwd() + '/temp')[0]
    print(video_file)
    audio_file = video_file.replace('mp4','mp3')
    clip = mp.VideoFileClip(os.getcwd() + '/temp/' + video_file)
    clip.audio.write_audiofile(os.getcwd() + '/music/' + audio_file)
    clip = None
    time.sleep(2)
    os.remove(os.getcwd() + '/temp/' + video_file)

convert_mp4_to_mp3()
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, that did not do the trick. I set clip = None after it wrote the audio but the file is still open in ffmpeg.exe

Comment: [Broad smile] This is why programmers use versioning systems. Start with code that works. Make a modification to it that takes it closer to what you want. If that works make another mod. If not, find out how to correct the modification. Or go back and try a different way of doing the modification altogether. In short, proceed incrementally.

Comment: @JoeyB: Apologies: What I said is true but quite inapposite. Please see edit.